# Search a pattern just between 2 other patterns

Tags: linux, shell

I wonder how can I search for a certain pattern in file, but only AFTER another pattern appear and stop searching when it encounters the third pattern?
For example, consider the following piece of text:

```
ServiceMsg  : X
Printing BlockList :
Block number: 1
ServiceMsg  : Y
ServiceType : GMAP_REQ (1)
Application Context:
Version : GSM_VERSION_3 (3)
Block number: 2
ServiceMsg  : Z
```

Here I want to search for the `ServiceMsg` pattern, however only after `Block number` appears and do not continue the search after additional `Block number`. Thus the result must be only `ServiceMsg  : Y`.

**EDIT:**

These blocks come in threes:

```
.
Block number: 1
.
.
Block number: 2
.
.
Block number: 3
.
```

...And there it goes again

I want to be able to retrieve the occurrences of `ServiceMsg` between `Block number: 1` and `Block number: 2`and also between `Block number: 2` and `Block number: 3`.

Thanks!

Comment: But do you need each occurence between `Block number: 1` and `Block number: 2` or just the first occurence between those?

Comment: @Jan Hudec Hi. I want to be able to retrieve the occurrences of `ServiceMsg` between `Block number: 1` and `Block number: 2`and also between `Block number: 2` and `Block number: 3`.

Comment: `do not continue the search` is in conflict with your new edit.

Comment: @user unknown I understand that it seems confusing, but what I meant is that I do not want to scan for `ServiceMsg` until certain `Block number` is reached. The moment `Block number` is reached, I want to continue scanning for `ServiceMsg`. In other words, I don't want to scan for `ServiceMsg` when not between blocks. Hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Please re-write your question. The first part says you do not want 'ServiceMsg: Z', but the edit says you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### update after question rewriting:

```
sed -n '/Block number:/,/ServiceMsg/{n;/ServiceMsg/p;g}' service.txt
```

Searches for ServiceMsg after Block number patterns (g)lobally. If it finds a ServiceMsg, it reads the (n)ext line, since the last line is not included. Then matches `ServiceMsg`, (p)rints it (g)lobally (not just once). -n prevents printing in general.

Test file:

```
ServiceMsg  : X
Printing BlockList :
Block number: 1
ServiceMsg  : Y
ServiceMsg  : fail
ServiceType : GMAP_REQ (1)
Application Context:
Version : GSM_VERSION_3 (3)
Block number: 2
ServiceMsg  : Z
Block number: 3
ServiceMsg  : end
```

Output:

```
ServiceMsg  : Y
ServiceMsg  : Z
ServiceMsg  : end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the start and end patterns were unique, you would just do

```
sed -n '/start-pattern/,/end-pattern/s/searched-pattern/&/p'
```

but if there is also `Block number: 3` and `Block number: 4` and more down the line and you can't match on the whole line including the number, you will have to resort to `awk` or `perl`.

Edit: I supposed sed has the `g` command like `ed`, but it apparently does not, so we have to abuse `s` command. The `&` represents the original text, but of course different substitution may be done as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Actually there are always 3 blocks like these which then repeat. I will add to the question.

Comment: With the comments here and on the question, I think `sed -n '/Block number: 1/,/Block number: 3/g/ServiceMsg:/p'` should do what you want. Of course you can use `s` instead of `g` e.g. to strip the `ServiceMsg:` prefix or whatever.

Comment: I get a: `sed: -e expression #1, char 37: extra characters after command`

Comment: @userunknown: You are right. I assumed `g` will work in sed like it does in ed (and ex and vim), but it does not, so I modified the answer to use `s` command instead.

Comment: And did you test it? Does it work? I get empty output. (It is unhandy to test, since you only provide the explaining form, which has to be redacted before testing).

Answer (score 1):

`awk(1)` is a useful tool for this job (I'm using gawk here):

```
awk -- '
    /pattern 1/ { matched = 1 }
    /pattern 2/ && matched { print }
    /pattern 3/ && matched { exit }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^Block number:/ {b = !b} b && /^ServiceMsg/ {print}'
```

---

Update:

```
awk -F' *: +' '
    $1 == "Block number" {block = $2; found = 0}
    block && $1 == "ServiceMsg" {
        if (! found) {
            printf("block %s, %s\n", block, $0)
            found = 1
        }
    }
'
```